# SQL decreasing sum by a percentage

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like

| timestamp | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08.01.2023 | 1 | 5 |
| 07.01.2023 | 0 | 20 |
| 06.01.2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 05.01.2023 | 0 | 50 |
| 04.01.2023 | 0 | 50 |
| 03.01.2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 02.01.2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 01.01.2023 | 1 | 1 |

Type 1 means a deposit, type 0 means a withdrawal.
The thing is when a type is 1 then the amount is the exact amount the user deposited so we can just sum that but type 0 means a withdrawal in percentage.
What I'm looking for is to create another column with current deposited amount. For the example above it would look like that.

| timestamp | type | value | deposited |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08.01.2023 | 1 | 5 | 5.4 |
| 07.01.2023 | 0 | 20 | 1.4 |
| 06.01.2023 | 1 | 1 | 1.75 |
| 05.01.2023 | 0 | 50 | 0.75 |
| 04.01.2023 | 0 | 50 | 1.5 |
| 03.01.2023 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 02.01.2023 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 01.01.2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I can't figure out how to make a sum like this which would subtract percentage of previous total

Comment: Does your table have a timestamp or sequence column too?

Comment: Yes, it does have a timestamp

Comment: Add that column to your sample data and expected result.

Comment: Do you not have access to actual withdrawal amounts for those days?

Comment: @Rajat you don't need actual withdrawal amounts to solve this using SQL only.

Comment: Who decided to generate the data like this on the app side....just saying??

Comment: @AdrianWhite I know, but having access to that data would prevent an unnecessarily complicated solution (in case OP didn't foresee it coming)

Comment: @Rajat agree , if available, that would reduce complexity -> I'm learning to balance pragmatism and solving difficult problems elegantly with just SQL.  FYI Using a recursive view where the 'starting with' section does the % adjustments and union all part does the culmulative sum almost works -> just trying to make it look elegant :-)  So you're essentially splitting the cumulative from the withdrawl % so you get around the numeric overflow that happens with a case statement.

Comment: Note; while the recursive approach is easier to understand (and maintain), if you deal with series longer than 100 entries, you may encounter issues.  Much better to use the log/exponent approach if you have long series or performance matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to carry state over time, so ether need to use a UDTF to doing the carry work for you. Or use a [recursive CTE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html#recursive-ctes-and-hierarchical-data)

```
with data(transaction_date, type, value) as (
    select to_date(column1, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), column2, column3
    from values
        ('08.01.2023', 1, 5),
        ('07.01.2023', 0, 20),
        ('06.01.2023', 1, 1),
        ('05.01.2023', 0, 50),
        ('04.01.2023', 0, 50),
        ('03.01.2023', 1, 1),
        ('02.01.2023', 1, 1),
        ('01.01.2023', 1, 1)
), pre_process_data as (
    select *
        ,iff(type = 0, 0, value)::number as add
        ,iff(type = 0, value, 0)::number as per
        ,row_number()over(order by transaction_date asc) as rn
    from data 
), rec_cte_block as (
    with recursive rec_sub_cte as (
        select 
            p.*,
            p.add::number(20,4) as deposited
        from pre_process_data as p
        where p.rn = 1
        
        union all 
        
        select 
            p.*,
            round(div0((r.deposited + p.add)*(100-p.per), 100), 2)  as deposited
        from rec_sub_cte as r
        left join pre_process_data as p
        where p.rn = r.rn+1
    )
    select * 
    from rec_sub_cte
)
select * exclude(add, per, rn)
from rec_cte_block
order by 1;
```

I wrote the recursive CTE this way, as there currently is an incident if IFF or CASE is used inside the CTE.

| TRANSACTION_DATE | TYPE | VALUE | DEPOSITED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-01-02 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2023-01-04 | 0 | 50 | 1.5 |
| 2023-01-05 | 0 | 50 | 0.75 |
| 2023-01-06 | 1 | 1 | 1.75 |
| 2023-01-07 | 0 | 20 | 1.4 |
| 2023-01-08 | 1 | 5 | 6.4 |

Comment: is Match_Recognize() technically a UDF or SQL?

Comment: @AdrianWhite it is not User Defined, nor a function, it is a expression construct. aka SQL. it's not a "standard SQL" but that is mostly pointless, it is a higher order expression of intent. And why simple for a "new person" to the code to grok, than hand rolling the same was basic SQL constructs.

Answer (score 2):

Solution without recursion and UDTF

```
create table depo (timestamp date,type int, value float);
insert into depo values
 (cast('01.01.2023' as date),1, 1.0)
,(cast('02.01.2023' as date),1, 1.0)
,(cast('03.01.2023' as date),1, 1.0)
,(cast('04.01.2023' as date),0, 50.0)
,(cast('05.01.2023' as date),0, 50.0)
,(cast('06.01.2023' as date),1, 1.0)
,(cast('07.01.2023' as date),0, 20.0)
,(cast('08.01.2023' as date),1, 5.0)
;
with t0 as(
select *
  ,sum(case when type=0 and value>=100 then 1 else 0 end)over(order by timestamp) gr
from depo
)
,t1 as (select timestamp as dt,type,gr
  ,case when type=1 then value else 0 end depo
  ,case when type=0 then ((100.0-value)/100.0) else 0.0 end pct
  ,sum(case when type=0 and value<100  then log((100.0-value)/100.0,2.0) 
            when type=0 and value>=100 then null
       else 0.0 
       end)
     over(partition by gr order by timestamp ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW 
         AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) totLog
from t0
)
,t2 as(
select * 
  ,case when type=1 then
      isnull(sum(depo*power(cast(2.0 as float),totLog))
            over(partition by gr order by dt rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
            ,0)/power(cast(2.0 as float),totLog)
      +depo
   else
      isnull(sum(depo*power(cast(2.0 as float),totLog))
           over(partition by gr order by dt rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
         ,0)/power(cast(2.0 as float),totLog)*pct
   end rest
from t1
)
select dt,type,depo,pct*100 pct
  ,rest-lag(rest,1,0)over(order by dt) movement
  ,rest
from t2
order by dt
```

| dt | type | depo | pct | movement | rest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-02-01 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 2023-03-01 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 2023-04-01 | 0 | 0 | 50 | -1.5 | 1.5 |
| 2023-05-01 | 0 | 0 | 50 | -0.75 | 0.75 |
| 2023-06-01 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1.75 |
| 2023-07-01 | 0 | 0 | 80 | -0.35 | 1.4 |
| 2023-08-01 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 5 | 6.4 |

I think, it is better to perform this kind of calculations on client side or  middle level.
Sequential calculations are difficult to implement in Sql. In some special cases, you can use logarithmic expressions. But it is clearer and easier to implement through recursion, as @Simeon showed.

Comment: Or, do them at insert time. Everytime a record is inserted (or updated/deleted) trigger a calculation. Whatever approach is taken, doing this at "report time" is generally a costly choice.

Comment: I played with this so I could properly understand it, and the `/ exp(totLog)` was the genius step.  Thank you.  In so doing I've managed to remove the larger `CASE` expression by offsetting the windows by one; [Demo with both code versions and an expanded test data set](https://dbfiddle.uk/JjnjRI8g)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [@ValNik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75358019/53341)

The fist simple step is to change "deduct 20%, then deduct 50%, then deduct 30%" in to a multiplication...

```
  X - 20% - 50% - 30%
  =>
  x * 0.8 * 0.5 * 0.7
  => 
  x * 0.28
```

The second trick is to understand how to calculate cumulative `PRODUCT()` when you only have cumulative sum; `SUM() OVER ()`, using the properties of logarithms...

```
  a * b == exp( log(a) + log(b) )

  0.8 * 0.5 * 0.7
  =>
  exp( log(0.8) + log(0.5) + log(0.7) )
  =>
  exp( -0.2231 + -0.6931 + -0.3567 )
  =>
  exp( -1.2730 )
  =>
  0.28
```

The next trick is easier to explain with integers rather than percentages.  That is to be able to break down the original problem in to one that can be solved using "cumulative sum" and "cumulative product"...

***Current working:***

| row_id | type | value | equation | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `+` | `10` | `0 + 10` | `10` |
| 2 | `+` | `20` | `(0 + 10 + 20)` | `30` |
| 3 | `*` | `2` | `(0 + 10 + 20) * 2` | `60` |
| 4 | `+` | `30` | `(0 + 10 + 20) * 2 + 30` | `90` |
| 5 | `*` | `3` | `((0 + 10 + 20) * 2 + 30) * 3` | `270` |

***Rearranged working:***

| row_id | type | value | CUMPROD | new equation | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `+` | `10` | `2*3=6` | `(10*6 ) / 6` | `10` |
| 2 | `+` | `20` | `2*3=6` | `(10*6 + 20*6 ) / 6` | `30` |
| 3 | `*` | `2` | `3=3` | `(10*6 + 20*6 ) / 3` | `60` |
| 4 | `+` | `30` | `3=3` | `(10*6 + 20*6 + 30*3) / 3` | `90` |
| 5 | `*` | `3` | `=1` | `(10*6 + 20*6 + 30*3) / 1` | `270` |

CUMPROD is the "cumulative product" of all ***future*** "multiplication values".

The equation is then the "cumulative sum" of `value * CUMPROD` divided by the current `CUMPROD`.

So...

- row 1 : `SUM(10*6            ) / 6` => `SUM(10    )`
- row 2 : `SUM(10*6, 20*6      ) / 6` => `SUM(10, 20)`
- row 3 : `SUM(10*6, 20*6      ) / 3` => `SUM(10, 20) * 2`
- row 4 : `SUM(10*6, 20*6, 30*3) / 3` => `SUM(10, 20) * 2   + SUM(30)`
- row 5 : `SUM(10*6, 20*6, 30*3) / 1` => `SUM(10, 20) * 2*3 + SUM(30) * 3`

The only things to be cautious of are:

- LOG(0) = Infinity (which would happen when deducting 100%)
- Deducting more than 100% makes no sense

So, I copied @ValNik's code that creates a new partition every time 100% or more is deducted (forcing everything in the next partition to start at zero again).

This gives the following SQL (a re-arranged version of @ValNik's code):

```
WITH
  partition_when_deduct_everything AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN type = 0 AND value >= 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    )
    OVER (
      ORDER BY timestamp
    )
      AS deduct_everything_id,
    CASE WHEN type   = 1   THEN value
                           ELSE 0
    END
      AS deposit,
    CASE WHEN type   = 1   THEN 1.0                 -- Deposits == Deduct 0%
         WHEN value >= 100 THEN 1.0                 -- Treat "deduct everything" as a special case
                           ELSE (100.0-value)/100.0 -- Change "deduct 20%" to "multiply by 0.8"
    END
      AS multiplier
  FROM
    your_table
)
,
  cumulative_product_of_multipliers as
(
  SELECT
    *,
    EXP(
      ISNULL(
        SUM(
          LOG(multiplier)
        )
        OVER (
          PARTITION BY deduct_everything_id
              ORDER BY timestamp
          ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING
                   AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
        )
        , 0
      )
    )
      AS future_multiplier
  FROM
    partition_when_deduct_everything
)
SELECT
  *,
  ISNULL(
    SUM(
      deposit * future_multiplier
    )
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY deduct_everything_id
          ORDER BY timestamp
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
               AND CURRENT ROW
    ),
    0
  )
  /
  future_multiplier
    AS rest
FROM
  cumulative_product_of_multipliers
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/mrioIMiB

Comment: thank's for detailed reasoning and explanation. Log(0) is a problem, fortunately, has a good solution.

Comment: yikes, this is bending my head.. I knew about the multiply -> log sum part of the trick, but  am still much to learn of the weaving them both together.. more play is required. But at this level of tricks, the UDTF actually becomes so superior imho.. as the carry is so tiny, and is a floating product...

Comment: the carried devisor, is accumulated in row_id desc order, yes? ah, `ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` so yes, but no, but yes.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim - I doubt I can explain in a comment anything I failed to explain in the answer, but I'll try...  At row 3: you ***want*** `(10 + 20) * 2` but you get `(10*6 + 20*6) / 3`; which is done because the `10*6` is 'easy' to get *(cumulative product of all multiplicands following the 10)* and the `/3` is 'easy' to get *(cumulative product of all multiplicands following row 3)*.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim - The problem with recursive queries is that they're relatively slow, especially over long series.  Especially if you encounter the RDBMS's recursion limit (over-ride it lets the query run, but it's still increasingly slow).  I have no knowledge about Snowflake and it's UDTF's, but I see they're defined using SQL and so I would presume have the same limitations as SQL without the functional encapsulation?  The query is complex to get your head around the first time, but once that's achieved it's just cumulative products and cumulative sums.

Answer (score 1):

So how this should be solved, is a UDTF, because it requires to "sorting the data once" and "traversing the data only once", and if you have different PARTITIONS aka user_id etc etc you can work in parallel):

```
create or replace function carry_value_state(_TYPE float, _VALUE float)
returns table (DEPOSITED float)
language javascript
as
$$
{
    initialize: function(argumentInfo, context) {
     this.carried_value = 0.0;
    },
    processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context){
        if(row._TYPE === 1) {
            this.carried_value += row._VALUE;  
        } else {
            let limited = Math.max(Math.min(row._VALUE, 100.0), 0.0);
            this.carried_value -= (this.carried_value * limited) / 100;          
        }
        rowWriter.writeRow({DEPOSITED: this.carried_value});
    }
}
$$;
```

which then gets used like:

```
select d.*,
    c.*
from data as d
    ,table(carry_value_state(d.type::float, d.value::float) over (order by transaction_date)) as c
order by 1;
```

so for the data we have been using in the example, that gives:

| TRANSACTION_DATE | TYPE | VALUE | DEPOSITED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-01-02 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2023-01-04 | 0 | 50 | 1.5 |
| 2023-01-05 | 0 | 50 | 0.75 |
| 2023-01-06 | 1 | 1 | 1.75 |
| 2023-01-07 | 0 | 20 | 1.4 |
| 2023-01-08 | 1 | 5 | 6.4 |

yes, the results are now in floating point, so you should double round to avoid FP representation problems, like:

```
round(round(c.deposited, 6) , 2) as deposited
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using Match_Recognize(), POW(), SUM().

I would not recommend using Match_Recognize() unless you have too, it's fiddly and can waste time, however does look elegant.

[image]

```
with data(transaction_date, type, value) as (
select
    to_date(column1, 'dd.mm.yyyy'),
    column2,
    column3
from
values
    ('08.01.2023', 1, 5),
    ('07.01.2023', 0, 20),
    ('06.01.2023', 1, 1),
    ('05.01.2023', 0, 50),
    ('04.01.2023', 0, 50),
    ('03.01.2023', 1, 1),
    ('02.01.2023', 1, 1),
    ('01.01.2023', 1, 1)
)  
select
    *
from
data match_recognize(
    order by
        transaction_date measures  
        sum(iff(CLASSIFIER() = 'ROW_WITH_DEPOSIT', value, 0)) DEPOSITS,
        pow(iff(CLASSIFIER() = 'ROW_WITH_WITHDRAWL', value / 100, 1) ,count(row_with_withdrawl.*))   DISCOUNT_FROM_WITHDRAWL,
        CLASSIFIER() TRANS_TYPE, 
        first(transaction_date) as start_date,
        last(transaction_date) as end_date,
        count(*) as rows_in_sequence,
        count(row_with_deposit.*) as num_deposits,
        count(row_with_withdrawl.*) as num_withdrawls 
    after
        match skip PAST LAST ROW pattern((row_with_deposit + | row_with_withdrawl +)) define row_with_deposit as type = 1,
        row_with_withdrawl as type = 0
);
```