# Use previously calculated value in the same column (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to access previously calculated value in Snowflake? What I'm trying to do is calculate "Remaining stock" based on previously calculated value minus the forecast + incoming stock, so:

remaining_stock = remaining_stock (pevious week) - forecasted_sales + incoming_stock

The calculation also needs to handle 0s, so the remaining stock shouldn't go below 0

I've already tried LAG, NTH_VALUE and running total calculation combos to achieve this but with no luck so far

Here's an example dataset, let's say the remaining stock for the opening week is set to 14 and the rest needs to be calculated based on fcasts:

| week_ending | sales_fcast | incoming_stock | remaining_stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-17 | 0 | 0 | 14 |
| 2024-02-24 | 6 | 0 | 8 |
| 2024-03-02 | 7 | 0 | 1 |
| 2024-03-09 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| 2024-03-16 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| 2024-03-23 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| 2024-03-30 | 12 | 28 | 16 |
| 2024-04-06 | 10 | 0 | 6 |
| 2024-04-13 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 2024-04-20 | 10 | 53 | 43 |
| 2024-04-27 | 11 | 0 | 32 |

tried LAG, NTH_VALUE and running total calculation combos to achieve this but with no luck so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LAG can carry an accumulator IF you are happy with negative number (or exceeding a limit) but if you want values to be clipped/limited, and then have that clipped/limited be the source of the next row this is carried state.

Two ways to solve this is with a recursive CTE, or a User Defined Tabular Function, with the later scaling much better, albeit a little harder to do.

example of UDTF
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75378334/43992

and here is a another solution with a [SUM that cannot be below zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59829731/running-total-of-positive-and-negative-numbers-where-the-sum-cannot-go-below-zer/59832844#59832844)

this question also has a recursive solution, but I'd strongly advise to use the [UDTF method](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/udf-js-table-functions.html).

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about UDTFs! Sounds like this could work, will look into this

Answer (score 0):

You are on right path, we need to use lag, and to handle negatives we need to use case.
Below is sample code.

```
select *
, lag(remaining_stock) over(order by week_ending) last_week_stock
, ifnull( case when last_week_stock - SALES_FCAST + INCOMING_STOCK <0
                    then 0
                else last_week_stock - SALES_FCAST + INCOMING_STOCK 
          end
  ,remaining_stock) Current_remaining_stock
from stocks;
```